# Pyspark: How to setup multiple JDBC connections?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

**Usecase**: I have two databases, one for prod and one for dev. The prod uses an SAP JDBC driver, and the dev uses an Oracle JDBC driver as they are based on different DB's. I have to fetch data from prod DB, perform few operations and save it in dev DB for few project needs.

**Issue**: Currently am using these third-party drivers by setting "spark.driver.extraClassPath" in Spark Context. But this takes in only one argument. Thus, I am able to connect to only one of the DB's at a time.

Is there are any way I can make two different JDBC class path configuration? If not, then how can I approach this issue? Any guidance is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Instead of defining the driver file path, providing the folder path loads all drivers in that folder. So, in my case, I placed both the SAP and Oracle JDBC drivers in same folder and mentioned it in the Spark Context Configuration like shown in the below snippet.

`.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", r"<folder_path_jdbc_drivers>\*")`